# Excel 2003 Macro: Aggregating data across several different workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

I wanted to create a macro using excel 2003 for a group of excel files where I can aggregate only the data I need to see into one s/s; the only problem is that I have no idea where to start. I am using a directory at work where I save down about 15-20 excel s/s' into a daily date labeled folder. To expedite our daily process of having to look into each s/s, search for the correct tab (which sometimes doesn't exist for that particular day) in the workbook, sort by data filter, and check it against list of identification codes; I would much rather create this in a macro. So I am looking for the macro to open today's dated folder in the directory, find the correct labeled tab (let's call it NYK123), open each file to match the id codes (in column H) and department codes (in column J) against the table I have on the original s/s, and display the results on the original s/s. Also new issues have the entire rows font is red and need to be displayed in the original s/s. Any help you guys can provide would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start you going:

```
Dim oFSO As New Scripting.FileSystemObject

Dim fsoFile As Scripting.file
Dim fsoFolder As Scripting.Folder

Dim sReportsFolder As String: sReportsFolder = "C:\temp\"

Set fsoFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(sReportsFolder)

For Each fsoFile In fsoFolder.Files

   Dim xlWorkbook As New Workbook
   Set xlWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(fsoFile.Name)

   Dim xlWorksheet As Worksheet
   Set xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

   ' put your logic here...

Next
```

**WARNING: written from memory, should compile**

Comment: Thank you for starting me off on this! When I try to put the actual directory parth instead of "C:\temp\" its giving me this message: "Compile error: Invalid outside procedure". What does this mean?

Comment: my mistake - you need to add Miscrosoft Scripting Runtime to the references: Tools -> References -> Miscrosoft Scripting Runtime, click on "Add" (as far as remember)

Comment: it's still giving the same error...I am starting to understand it a littel bit better though.

Comment: thanks for your help Juliusz!! I am just having trouble though with figuring out how to pull it from a new daily file every day.

Comment: Here is an example: Intellimatch Daily\2012\09_Sept 2012\09-11-2012

Comment: Can anyone else help explain the errors I am getting on this report?